# Angular Universal generate 404 (and other HTTP codes) header

Tags: angular, seo, angular-universal

I'm creating a website using Angular Universal. It will have server-side rendering in order to make it indexable by search engines.

I already coded my 404 fallback route, it displays its component correctly, but it displays it with a HTTP 200 header code.

How can I force a specific header code ? I googled some queries, but everything I found seemed to be about *reading* an HTTP call's status code, and nothing on how to *write* it to the browser.

Comment: ... and it's status code.

Comment: Sorry, i should have added emphasis on the "reading", which is something I don't care for now, since I want to "write" a response code to the browser.

Comment: You can't write a response to the browser, the browser works on HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've finally succeeded.

I started over, and used [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) (CLI), with Patrick Michalina's scripts described here : https://github.com/DSpace/dspace-angular/issues/91#issuecomment-318547118

Comment: Please help me out for Angular 9 Same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't tuch any project related to angular since then

Answer (score 6):

I followed the docs:
https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine

Note, you bootstrap the app twice in server.ts, we need to provide the response every request.
Also we optionally inject the response into our app components, as the response will be NULL if the platform is the browser.

server.ts

some imports:

```
import {Response} from 'express';
import {RESPONSE} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
```

engine:

```
// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
  ]
}));
```

request handler:

```
app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.html', {req, res, providers: [
      {
        provide: RESPONSE,
        useValue: res,
      },
    ]}, (error, html) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`Error generating html for req ${req.url}`, error);
      return (req as any).next(error);
    }
    res.send(html);
    if (!error) {
      if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        //toCache(req.url, html);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
...
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}

];
```

component:

```
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens'
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core'
import { Response } from 'express'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.scss']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {
  private response: Response;
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) response: any) {
    this.response = response;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('here with response', this.response);
    if (this.response) {
      // response will only be if we have express
      // this.response.statusCode = 404;
      this.response.status(404);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: please help me out for angular 9 with this same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code

Answer (score 1):

After a long research, here what i have found

https://skynix.co/resources/how-to-set-404-status-code-in-angular

**page-not-found.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ContentfulService } from '../../contentful/services/contentful.service';
import { CoreService } from '../../core/services/core.service';
import { Utils } from '../../core/utils/utils';
import { PageNotFound } from './interfaces/page-not-found';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-not-found',
  templateUrl: './page-not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-not-found.component.scss'],
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent {
  richTextRenderer = Utils.returnHtmlFromRichText;
  data$: Observable<PageNotFound> = this.contentfulService.get404Page();
  locale$ = this.coreService.currentLocale$;
  private response: Response;

  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
    private coreService: CoreService,
    private router: Router,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private dom: Document,
    @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) response: any
  ) {
    this.response = response;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.response) {
      this.response.status(404);
    }
  }
}
```