# Angular universal redirect 404 page not found

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

i have a project in angular universal connected to firebase with firebasecloud for the ssr.
when i try to go to a page that doesn't exist in routing i get a 403 error and it doesn't bring me back to the correct page.
I am shown this page
[image]

These are my files:
server.ts:

```
export function app() {
    const server = express();
    const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/ricicla-risparmia-rinnova/browser');
    const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

    // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
    server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    }));

    server.set('view engine', 'html');
    server.set('views', distFolder);

    // Example Express Rest API endpoints
    // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
    // Serve static files from /browser
    server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
        maxAge: '1y'
    }));

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.render(indexHtml, {req, providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl}]});
    });


    return server;
}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'login', canActivate: [AuthAdminGuard], component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'articolo', loadChildren: () => import('./components/articolo/articolo.module').then(m => m.ArticoloModule)},
    {path: 'admin', canActivate: [AuthAdminGuard], loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)},
    {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '404'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

here I am sharing a working example for the same I hope this solves the problem!
[check this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-5vtp7b?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts)

your code seems to be correct if my example code does not solve your problem kindly share the error or the working example code with the bug you are facing.

Comment: your project has no universal, if I start my project locally the redirect works, once it is in prod with the ssr it no longer works and gives me that error page

Comment: what do you mean by "no universal"? if you have SSR issue then probably something is getting overwritten by your server configuration(Nginx/apache). because if the URL is not matching the given path it will fall back to give the path.

Comment: I use firebase for hosting and the ssr is always in the cloud function of firebase, the server configuration I put it above

Comment: look at this one this might help you! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56015306/3893124)

Answer (score 0):

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'login', canActivate: [AuthAdminGuard], component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'articolo', loadChildren: () => import('./components/articolo/articolo.module').then(m => m.ArticoloModule)},
    {path: 'admin', canActivate: [AuthAdminGuard], loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '404'}
];
```

you should be refactor it your code with like this.