# How to return 404 in angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Angular does not return an error 404 while surfing to a page that doesn’t exist and the status code is 200 OK.

Should not index in the google search engine as the response is 200 but the link is 404

[image]

[image]

Using Angular Universal, Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you searched on the website before positing a question? For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46219720) should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Finally found the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219720/angular-universal-generate-404-and-other-http-codes-header/76720722#76720722